# Adding a percentage Column to existing data in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have this as a answer since earlier today

```
SELECT  Users.full_name
        ,sum(total)
        ,sum(case when service < 49 then total else 0 end) AS Productive
FROM    time_report
        , users
WHERE   time_report.User = users.user_id
        AND date BETWEEN '2011-0502' AND '2011-05-11'
GROUP BY 
        User
```

THis gives me the following data back which is what I wanted

```
full_name   sum(total)  Productive

Cian Higgins    26  14

Wallace Ward    23  23

jason ward      42  33

Thomas Woods    72  53

Peter Jones     49  41

fintan corrigan 40  32

David Jones     35  27

January Jones   23  23

Joe Johnson     24  24
```

I am wondering it there a way to add an aditional column called percentage to the output which will give me the output from `Round((Total/productive) * 100)`

I have been struggling with this for most of the day.
I have  created  a temp table with the output from the original query, but am struggling with the right syntax to get the percentage entered into it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Am I missing something? Shouldn't this be `Round((productive/Total) * 100)` ?

Comment: Sorry, you are right of course...long day!:)

Comment: No worries, 3 answers from posters with 30k+ (in total) and no one caught it either :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  Users.full_name
        ,sum(total)
        ,sum(case when service < 49 then total else 0 end) AS Productive
        ,(Round((sum(total)/sum(case when service < 49 then total else 0 end)) * 100)) AS Percent
...
```

Comment: This answered my question, of course my query should have been Round((productive/Total) * 100) so by swapping around the line (Round((sum(total)/sum(case when service < 49 then total else 0 end)) to Round( sum( CASE WHEN service <49 THEN total
ELSE 0 END ) / ( sum( total ) ) *100 )...it worked a treat. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, *derived* columns can only be used by name in `ORDER BY`. That is to say you'd have to duplicate it in your `SELECT` columns versus being able to say `ROUND((Total/Productive) * 100)`:

```
SELECT  Users.full_name
        ,sum(total) AS Total
        ,sum(case when service < 49 then total else 0 end) AS Productive
        ,(ROUND(sum(total) / sum(case when service < 49 then total else 0 end)) * 100) AS Percentage
FROM    time_report
        , users
WHERE   time_report.User = users.user_id
        AND date BETWEEN '2011-0502' AND '2011-05-11'
GROUP BY User
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid repeating aggregate expressions by moving your original query into `FROM` clause.

```
SELECT full_name, Total, Productive, Round((Total/Productive) * 100) AS pcnt
FROM
(
SELECT  Users.full_name
    ,sum(total) As Total,
    ,sum(case when service < 49 then total else 0 end) AS Productive
 FROM    time_report
    , users
WHERE   time_report.User = users.user_id
    AND date BETWEEN '2011-0502' AND '2011-05-11'
GROUP BY 
    User
)a
```

Comment: Interesting. I'd be curious the performance implications though. I'd think it wouldn't performed any better. MySQL has to optimize matching expressions. So the sub-`SELECT` creates overhead.

Comment: @Jason McCreary : I'm not 100% sure that it creates a big overhead; that's possible, but I believe a smart optimizer can remove it. Also, I believe such an approach is less error-prone if you need to change something and more readable.

Comment: I didn't figure a big overhead. Just a curiosity what it did under the hood. Have to run `EXPLAIN` next time. Agreed on the maintainable bit. It's not the way I would write my queries. But it's nonetheless a good point.